# tree structure visualization

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have an AST (abstract syntax tree) structure that I need to visualize. What to use for such visualization? I have heard about eclipse gmf, but after a short look on all that models and code generation I think that it is too complex for this problem.

My task is only show tree structure with some basic interactive functions: I need to show popup window with some additional information and that is all.

Do you think that eclipse Draw2D is enough? Moreover may be there are some out of the box solutions for visualizing a tree structure?

Answer (score 1):

Try [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/).  It's an open source graph visualization software that can be used to generate images (SVG, PNG, JPEG,etc) from graph structures (including ASTs).

You can find a Java-based alternative in [Eclipse Zest](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/zest/), a group of visualization components for Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

It's not particularly sexy, but if you're looking for a low barrier of entry, a swing JTree is pretty easy to get started with.  The [Swing Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) have several examples.

Comment: There is not swing, there is swt.